# How to convert an HTML table to an Excel File using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, activex, export-to-excel

http://www.databison.com/index.php/html-to-excel-using-javascript-and-excel-to-html-using-vba/

This code needs ActiveX control support so it works in IE only, in Firefox or chrome in throws an error of ActiveX needed.

But in IE it some how doesn't export the table data into excel object.
Can I have few suggestions to make this export to excel work.

Comment: What specific behavior are you looking for?  Click a button and Excel opens on the user's computer with the table displayed as data in the workbook?  Embed Excel in the browser?

Comment: He is probably doing what the example in the link he provided showed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` when you are done copying the data? The example in the link you provided did not call `SaveAs`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Yes I tried using SaveAs....but no xls is getting saved. Only an empty excel file opens up.